# PostgreSQL / SQL: How to pass an argument to CREATE VIEW in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-14

PostgreSQL version: `PostgreSQL 14.8 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 12.2.1_git20220924-r10) 12.2.1 20220924, 64-bit`

I'm trying to create a stored procedure which accepts two arguments (a and b is for the sake of simplicity, their actual names are _service_id and _car_id).

According to [documentation on procedures in PostgreSQL 14](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createprocedure.html), you can use arguments without any additional syntax in procedure's body. Example provided by the documentation is as follows:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_data(a integer, b integer)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (a);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (b);
$$;
```

However it is not a case, when I am trying to write my own procedure. Running the following code makes me stumble upon an error:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_total_and_count_for_car_for_service (a int, b int)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
    CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW total_and_count_for_car_for_service_result AS (
        SELECT
            SUM(
                CASE WHEN cars.is_foreign THEN
                    services.cost_foreign
                ELSE
                    services.cost_our
                END) AS total,
            COUNT(works.id)
        FROM
            works
        LEFT JOIN cars ON cars.id = works.car_id
        LEFT JOIN services ON services.id = works.service_id
    WHERE
        works.service_id = a
        AND works.car_id = b
    GROUP BY
        works.car_id)
$$;
CALL get_total_and_count_for_car_for_service (2, 2);
SELECT * FROM total_and_count_for_car_for_service_result;
```

...and here goes an error:

```
car_service=# CALL get_total_and_count_for_car_for_service ( 2, 2);
ERROR:  column "a" does not exist
LINE 1: ...es.id = works.service_id WHERE works.service_id = a AND work...
                                                             ^
QUERY:   CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW total_and_count_for_car_for_service_result AS (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN cars.is_foreign THEN services.cost_foreign ELSE services.cost_our END) AS total, COUNT(works.id) FROM works LEFT JOIN cars ON cars.id = works.car_id LEFT JOIN services ON services.id = works.service_id WHERE works.service_id = a AND works.car_id = b GROUP BY works.car_id) 
CONTEXT:  SQL function "get_total_and_count_for_car_for_service" statement 1
```

What's going on and why my arguments are not visible to CREATE VIEW function, unlike in PostgreSQL documentation exmaple, where arguments are visible to INSERT? What would be a proper way to pass arguments in that case and make it work?

*Note: I am aware that this stored procedure should be a function rather than a stored procedure and storing result in a temporary view is a crutch. However, in general, creation of views via procedures is not something strange, imho.*

upd: db schema is created with following script

```sql
CREATE DATABASE car_service;
\c car_service;

CREATE TABLE cars (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    num VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    color VARCHAR(20),
    mark VARCHAR(20),
    is_foreign BOOLEAN
);

CREATE TABLE masters (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE services (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    cost_our NUMERIC(18, 2),
    cost_foreign NUMERIC(18, 2)
);
CREATE TABLE works (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    date_work DATE,
    master_id INT REFERENCES masters(id),
    car_id INT REFERENCES cars(id),
    service_id INT REFERENCES services(id)
);

ALTER TABLE works
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_works_cars
FOREIGN KEY (car_id)
REFERENCES cars(id);

ALTER TABLE works
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_works_masters
FOREIGN KEY (master_id)
REFERENCES masters(id);

ALTER TABLE works
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_works_services
FOREIGN KEY (service_id)
REFERENCES services(id);
```

Comment: Whats the type of your works.services_id ? I am not too familiar with procedures and functions but I tried a simplified version of your code and it works fine locally. No issues. This is what I tested: 
create table tbl (a integer, b integer);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_tbl (a int, b int)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
    CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW tbl_view AS (
        SELECT
            a,
            b
        FROM
            tbl
    WHERE
        tbl.a = a)
$$;
CALL get_tbl (2, 2);
SELECT * FROM tbl_view;

Comment: @Nick I updated the question, you can have a look at the schema. service_id is SERIAL, which is basically INT. I think your example is inappropriate because what I believe your query actually uses are fields of `tbl` and that `tbl.a = a` actually implies `tbl.a = tbl.a`. Have you tested it with data?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use parameters in a `CREATE VIEW` statement.

Use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE
   sql text;
BEGIN
   sql = format('CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW total_and_count_for_car_for_service_result ' ||
                'AS (SELECT ... ' ||
                'WHERE works.service_id = %s ' ||
                '  AND works.car_id = $s ...',
                a, b
         );

   EXECUTE sql;
END;
```

Comment: Are there any other ways to do that? Sure that does solve the issue, but the solution doesn't seem very *neat*... And why parameters can't be used in `CREATE VIEW` statement? Is there any kind of sensible idea behind this limitation?

Comment: If I knew of any other ways, I would have told you. Parameters cannot be used with `CREATE VIEW` because nobody implemented it. The sensible idea is that it is quite unnecessary. As the documentation for `PREPARE` will tell you, parameters can only be used with `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `MERGE` and `VALUES`.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep it simple, and use a function for this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_total_and_count_for_car_for_service(a INT, b INT)
    RETURNS TABLE
            (
                CAR_ID INT,
                TOTAL  NUMERIC,
                COUNT  BIGINT
            )
    LANGUAGE sql
AS
$$
SELECT works.car_id
     , SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN cars.is_foreign THEN
                services.cost_foreign
            ELSE
                services.cost_our
            END) AS total
     , COUNT(works.id)
FROM works
         LEFT JOIN cars ON cars.id = works.car_id
         LEFT JOIN services ON services.id = works.service_id
WHERE works.service_id = $1
  AND works.car_id = $2
GROUP BY works.car_id;
$$;

SELECT *
FROM get_total_and_count_for_car_for_service(2, 2);
```

There is no (performance) benefit from creating a (temporary) view first. It's slower and you have to use a database role that has enough permissions to create database objects. With this solution you don't need pl/pgsql either, just pl/sql and that's slightly faster as well.